# Cloud API: ConcurrentDataChangeException is thrown when using the Composite API

Tags: guidewire

We are trying to adopt the Cloud API and trying to move away from the custom Rest API. we are using the Composite API concept to construct the multiple request to create a Service Request on Claim but we are seeing the ConcurrentDataChangeException for some of the request. is there retry option available with in OOB configuration?

We use to see same exception for Custom Rest API and able to catch the exception and implemented the auto retries before throwing the exception back to caller. with this re-try we were able to process all the request without any issues.

i am not seeing any documentation how to retry these exception with in ClaimCenter for Cloud APIs instead of returning the exception back to caller and if the caller retry again ClaimCenter might behaves same way and could throw the exception. is anyone experiencing same issue or any work around?

Comment: Can you edit your answer and post the full stack trace of the exception you are seeing. This might help people in this forum give you a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is no OOTB way to retry a composite request.  Certainly the caller can catch and retry the request.

While you are analyzing the CDCE, please note that all of the requests in the composite are executed atomically.  It might be possible that the composite request creates the CDCE.  If retrying the request allows it to complete then this comment can be ignored.

Comment: To add to Edgars answer, when one step of your composite request triggers some async operation (like a messaging event, a workflow, or some other action) then you need to design a solution that will accommodate that result.  The likely most straightforward option would be to break apart the single composite request into two, potentially with a "get" operation in between to check if the prior actions are complete and ready for the next step.  While catching and retrying can be a viable design choice it's not the only, or even best one.